# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scrapy' for MAC OSX

Tags: python, module, scrapy

Using Python Version 2.7.10
I downloaded Scrapy and on Version 1.4.0
I'm questioning where exactly I need to have these installed? I changed my filename from scrapy.py to scrapy123.py to no avail.  I'm frustrated! ha

Receiving the infamous error of:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/william/PycharmProjects/scrapy123.py", line 1, in <module>
    import scrapy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scrapy'
```

Script:

```
import scrapy
    class BlogSpider(scrapy.Spider):
      name = 'blogspider'
      start_urls = ['https://blog.scrapinghub.com']

    def parse(self, response):
         for title in response.css('h2.entry-title'):
            yield {'title': title.css('a ::text').extract_first()}

               next_page = response.css('div.prev-post > a 
                     ::attr(href)').extract_first()
        if next_page:
            yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(next_page), 
callback=self.parse)
```

Comment: maybe it would be a good idea to use [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/userguide/) so you can define an actual environment that won't mess up with your system's installation

Comment: I've considered but seems like an extra step, and has just as many adverse problems. Which versions do I need to be on? Where does my module need to be installed?

Answer (score 0):

using the [pep-0328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#guido-s-decision) `__future__` `absolute_import` helps to make this less ambiguous and has been supported from 2.5.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```

Then you can simply `import .scrappy` and make sure it is loading the version expected.  It will also help when moving to Python3

Comment: where exactly do I need to place the from __future__ import absolute_import - into my created folder? Also, the import .scrappy - did you mean import .scrapy?

Comment: Sorry about the typo, it should be the first import in the file or pylint will complain.

Comment: I added that as the first line and it's not even throwing a different error. Same thing. Never heard of pylint. Do I need to install this?

Comment: Where are you running the script from?  Are both python files in `/Users/william/PycharmProjects/`?

Comment: Yes regarding scrapy.py (renamed from ..123) and not sure which other file you are talking about. I'm still scratching my head, reading the pep-0328 page... Also, when I run the script, it's simply by pressing Run/Play button in the PyCharm app.